# Cordova File Rename - Error 1000

Tags: android, file, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to rename file using Cordova File Plugin. It gives me error with `Code 1000` without any description. Here is code sample I am using

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    console.log('root url '+fileSystem.root.toURL());
    var entry = new FileEntry("Download/abc.pdf");

    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Download", {create: true, exclusive: false},
    function (directory) {
        entry.moveTo(directory, "file.pdf", success, fail);
    }, fail);
}

function success(fileEntry) {
    console.log("New Path: " + fileEntry.fullPath);
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
}
```

I have already placed `abc.pdf` in `Download` folder.
Not sure what I am doing wrong.

I am using Cordova 4.0.0 with Android (platform version 3.4.0)

Comment: maybe try to use resolveLocalFileSystemURI instead of new FileEntry to get the original file entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked but with following way,

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("Download/abc.pdf", {}, function(file){
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Download", {}, function (directory) {
        file.moveTo(directory, "file.pdf", success, fail);
    }, function(error){
        console.log(error,"Directory Error ");
    });
}, function(error){
    console.log(error,"File Error ");
});
```

I got a dirty (?) working version of same as

```
var entry = new FileEntry("abc.pdf");
entry.fullPath = "//Download/abc.pdf";
entry.nativeURL = fileSystem.root.toURL() + "Download/abc.pdf";
entry.filesystem = new FileSystem('persistent');

var dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("Download");
dirEntry.fullPath = "//Download/";
dirEntry.nativeURL = fileSystem.root.toURL() + "Download/";
dirEntry.filesystem = new FileSystem('persistent');

entry.moveTo(dirEntry, "file.pdf", success, fail);
```